# Flat UI design for android

Tags: android-layout, design-patterns

I have completely finished my android application and now want to make come UI design changes. i searched everywhere on the internet but couldn't find how to change my application UI design to flat.

Could someone tell me how I could create a UI design which is flat.

Comment: the easiest way to do this is using the Android FlatUI Kit. You can find it on GitHub page here: https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to transform whatever you have to flat design? One does not simply do that. If you made your app in Eclipse, I suggest you mock up the UI in Photoshop or Illustrator first then modify the XML file to match what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the style.XML of your xml so that Buttons look different. Everything else basically already is flat on android (edittext, list view...). So check out how to apply custom style by extending the standard styles.